# How to delete a HTree Indexed Directory in Linux

Tags: debian, permissions

I'm trying to delete a folder that is flagged indexed without success.

```shellsession
# lsattr folder
-----------I--e------- folder

# rm folder -r 
rm: cannot remove 'folder': Operation not permitted
```

How can I remove the directory or the `I` flag?

Comment: Have you tried "sudo rm -r folder" ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it as root. Also tried to mount the partition with a debian rescue shell from a USB stick. I always get Operation not permitted.

Comment: The 'e' attribute indicates that the file is using extents
              for mapping the blocks on disk.  It may not be removed
              using chattr(1).